# Control iOS gps input

Tags: ios, gps, maps

I have a problem with iPhone GPS ; i'm trying to record a track that is not on a street , but each time I pass near a street ( look at enclosed image ) it seems to me that the gps output is corrected with maps data ;
Is there a way to disable this beahviour ? I need the precise point in my app

[image: track from iphone]

Comment: Is this your app you have written! or a foreign one? Do you use MkMapKit? ios 6?

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the "snap to road" feature, set the `activityType` to `CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation`.  All other values (Other, Fitness, AutoNav) for activityType will snap to the nearest road.

This was the advice we received from an Apple engineer at WWDC recently.  We also verified this (on iOS 7.1.2) by taking 4 iPhone 5 devices (one for each activityType, plus a Trimble GPS for reference) and doing extensive testing on and off roads (see map below).

We have not tested on iOS 8 yet, this behavior could change, since it is undocumented.

Caution: if there is more than one instance of `CLLocationManager` in your app, they must be set to the same `activityType`.  If they have different values, the first one started may be the one that determines how they all behave, we had problems with this too.  `MKMapView` creates its own `CLLocationManager`, for example.

Here is a sample of our test results.  The orange line is `CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation`, the blue, green and red are the other 3 activity types.  You can see that the blue, green and red follow the center line of the road, while the orange line uses the raw GPS position.

[image]

Comment: Yes, same conclusion for me. Another important thing to point is that this beahviour occures only above a thresold speed, so that it may seem that apps are not affected by this issue if they are verified when iphone is stopped. And another important thing to point is that this setting has implications on battery , as it disables other things that would optimize battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your post was shocking me, I immediately tried it out on my app.
On ios6 using Apples MKMapKit, positions are not snapped to a near street. At least not with standard settings. 
(Neither on ios5)

I wonder how the app is able to snap to the next street, I know how to do that pricipally, but the vector data are not available from Apple.

So please can you talk with the SW developers of the App how they snap to the next road?
(Using OpenStreetMap vector data this could work, but Apple uses TomTom vector data which are not public available)

Comment: The app is on itunes: https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/dashcam-pro/id617433852?mt=8 i hoped it was something releated to precision, but i have tried both best and bestfornavigation with no difference , and other acuuracy are not enough ;  
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        // filtro poi i valori prima di mandarli al delegato
        //_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

Comment: Which device? Iphone3G, iPhond4, 5? Post more details, Which API, minimum ios version to run, etc. So you are sure that you or your colleagues do not snap the positions to the road?

Comment: iPhone4s , i have found this; http://ilquest.com/2012/11/02/ios-6-is-unusable-for-people-relying-on-accurate-gps-tracks/ it semestre related to speed, above a certain speed gps snaps to road. Maybe i should set clactivitytype (?)

Comment: Ok, it seems there's a key in info.plist :  NSLocationUsageDescription ( from ios6 , it was purpose property before )

Comment: Thanks a lot, for some reasons my app is not affected, but good to know that there exist that CLActivityFitness setting.

Comment: In any case, just for people who will read this post, the right field is activityType in CLLocationManager, that affects other things too ( for example, the time elapsed before location manager is suspended when you stop); be aware that this functionality is for ios6 only ( maybe depends by the platform you deploy) and is enabled when speed is above a thresold and map data is available

Comment: @atrebbi can you please post this valuable info as your own answer.